# Do any iPhone 5 docking stations offer both audio out and a lightning connector for charging?

Tags: audio, iphone, lightning

What iPhone 5 docking stations are on the market that provide an analog audio out connection similar to [Apple's iPhone 4 dock](http://store.apple.com/us_smb_78313/product/MC596ZM/B/apple-iphone-4-dock)?

I currently use the above dock with my 4S for charging at night, but if I make an upgrade to the new iPhone, I'd like a Lightning dock.

EDIT: I found [one option on Amazon](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00AE2D10U), but it appears to be low quality (some ship with Lightning port in the back, others with 30-pin port). I'm also concerned that plugging a 1/8" jack into the headphone port will effectively silence my morning alarms.

Comment: Be aware that hardware shopping questions are discouraged. If there is some need that you weren't able to research or some requirements you are not sure of, explaining that will generally make "recommendation" questions more popular or likely to not be closed.

Comment: @bmike This isn't a "recommendation" question. I haven't been able to find any of these stations with a line out for audio.

Comment: Since you hadn't asked many questions here, I just wanted to raise your awareness that some would consider this a recommendation since you only mentioned the audio portion as an occasional use item. I edited things to make that be a requirement. Feel free to continue to edit it if other answers are not really what you are hoping to find.

Comment: @bmike Thanks for the edits. I'm much more used to using Stack Overflow.

Comment: It's a great question which is why I wanted to help it shine :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An OEM dock just popped up in store.apple.com after the 9/10 event: http://store.apple.com/us/product/MF030ZM/A/iphone-5s-dock

Answer (score 0):

From Apple's site is the [Belkin dock for iPhone 5](https://www.apple.com/shop/iphone/iphone-accessories/power-cables).

[image]

Comment: This one doesn't have a line audio out.

Comment: Ah, indeed it doesn't. I missed that aspect of your question.